# Understanding a few of the 'helper' gnu-as directives

Tags: c, assembly, gcc, x86, gnu-assembler

I have compiled a program `main.c` with about two lines of code to see what directives `gcc` / `gas` add to the unoptimized assembly file, using:

```
gcc -o main.s main.c -S
```

I can look up the concise description of each directive on the [gas directive](https://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/Manuals/gas-2.9.1/html_chapter/as_7.html) page, but was hoping someone could give a bit more context to some of these directives and what its practical usage is (for example, in `gdb` or the `linker` or wherever downstream). Here is the full assembly file with the items in question below:

```
    .file   "main.c"
    .text
    .globl  main
    .type   main, @function
main:
.LFB0:
    .cfi_startproc
    pushq   %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
    .cfi_offset 6, -16
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_register 6
    movl    $4, -8(%rbp)
    movl    $6, -4(%rbp)
    movl    -8(%rbp), %edx
    movl    -4(%rbp), %eax
    addl    %edx, %eax
    popq    %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa 7, 8
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
.LFE0:
    .size   main, .-main
    .ident  "GCC: (Ubuntu 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04) 7.5.0"
    .section    .note.GNU-stack,"",@progbits
```

1. [`.file`](https://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/Manuals/gas-2.9.1/html_chapter/as_7.html#SEC90): it seems this is halfway-obsolete based on *This statement may go away in future: it is only recognized to be compatible with old `as` programs.*. But given that it is still there, where or how is this currently being used?
2. [`.ident`](https://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/Manuals/gas-2.9.1/html_chapter/as_7.html#SEC95): it seems like this gives the same thing as doing `gcc --version`. Is this used at all beyond giving helper information on the 'gcc' that was used to issue the command, or how is this used?
3. [`.section .note...`](https://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/Manuals/gas-2.9.1/html_chapter/as_7.html#SEC119): I have seen `.section .text`, `.section .bss`, `.section .text`, ...but I've never come across a `.note`, and doing a ctrl-f to search for `note` doesn't give anything on this page. What is this line doing with the three arguments? And the `@progbits` ?
4. [`.size`](https://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/Manuals/gas-2.9.1/html_chapter/as_7.html#SEC123): given that the directives take up no space, this is giving us the length of the first statement within `main` -- `pushq %rbp` minus the last statement `ret`, which is the length of the `main` function. But again, what usage is this? Also, it says on the `as` page that *It is only permitted inside .def/.endef pairs.*, but this isn't inside those pairs, right?
5. `.section    .text.startup,"ax",@progbits` -- what is `text.startup`, the `ax` looks like it means allocatable+executable, but what or where is the `text.startup` ?

Comment: 3) You can name your sections anything you like, but some are used by tools such as the `.note.GNU-stack` which is used to control executable stack. 4) The size is the size of the whole function. It's used for finding function boundaries. The `.def`/`.enddef` only applies to COFF, not ELF.

Comment: @Jester thanks, where can I learn more about the `.note.GNU-stack` ?

Comment: Just google it, for example [here](https://www.airs.com/blog/archives/518). It's little more than a placeholder to specify executable or not for the stack.

Comment: The `.ident` section places the string that follows into the `.comment` section.  This is used for various other things as well, like placing SVN version identifiers into binaries.  The `#ident` directive in C code can be used to generate `.ident` assembly directives.

Comment: @fuz I see, thanks for pointing that out: `$ readelf -x .comment file2` allows me to find it too. Is there a way to manually add in a comment as well (that gets passed to elf)? For example, something like `.comment "Hello"` ?

Comment: You can switch to the `.section .comment` and emit stuff, presumably.

Comment: @Jester I see. But within that `.comment` section how to actually write a comment (i.e., a string) ?

Comment: Using the normal directives such as `.string "whatever"`

Comment: @Jester thanks for the tip, that worked! Now I have `.ident  "GCC: (Ubuntu 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04) 7.5.0"
.section .comment
.string "-- And an additional comment by me"` and I can view it all in the `.comment` section.

Comment: @David542 You can just add in `.ident` directives yourself.  There can be as many as you want in one file.  For example, I often mark copyright in assembly source files of mine this way.